# OSGi Tutorials without Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I want to develop an OSGi module.
However I don't want to rely on Eclipse, but rather develop the module in vim
and build it with maven.

Also, I would find it nice to have a live deployment.
Therefore I am searching for something which watches my files for changes
similar to build systems in nodejs and then recompiles the project and deploys it.

Does anybody know how to do this, or knows a tutorial which might describe this?

Comment: This question is likely to be deleted, as StackOverflow frowns on requests for links to external resources. You could ask over on the [osgi-dev mailing list](https://mail.osgi.org/mailman/listinfo/osgi-dev) instead.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to develop an OSGI module ... in vim and build it with maven.

Perhaps this [tutorial Using OSGi enRoute with Maven](http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_eval/050-start.html) will get you started!